# How to ignore .gitignore file from commiting by EGit plugin of Apatana Studio 2?

Tags: git, eclipse-plugin, gitignore, egit, aptana

I have been using the Git bash for doing my commits until now and have never seen .gitignore file getting commited. Recently I moved over to Aptana Studio 2 for doing my projects and installed the **EGit Eclipse Plugin** for version control. Whenever I commit now the **.gitignore** file also gets commited. I even tried to include the line `*.gitignore` in the .gitignore file itself, but that doesn't help.

How can I ignore the .gitignore file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *actual* answer to your question is (assuming the .gitignore file you are referring to is in the root of your project structure):

A.) If you're using windows make sure that .gitignore isn't a hidden file. Right click on the file in Windows Explorer and select properties, then make sure hidden isn't checked off. This has to do with an issue Eclipse based IDEs have with hidden files.

B.) Edit .gitignore and add the following on a line by itself:
/.gitignore

C.) Save the file then right click on it in Aptana and click on untrack under the team menu.

EGit should now parse the file as expected but not add it to version control.

Comment: This way `.gitignore` behaves exactly like the file defined in `core.excludesfile` (See http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore). You should describe why it should be useful to have to files, that (at the end) does the same.

Answer (score 7):

`.gitignore` should always be versioned with your project files to avoid, that someone else (or youself on another system) accidentally commit files, that may cause serious problems (e.g. files containing passwords, ..). If you want to exclude files, that are very specific to your local environment, you should place them somewhere else.

http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

In `$GIT_DIR/info/exclude` you can write the filenames, that should be ignored and that are specific to that project. In the file defined by `core.excludesfile` you can place files, that should be ignored in a more global way. Both files are (usually) not versioned.

Comment: The question he asked was how to ignore .gitignore, which you didn't actually answer. In either case, you're presenting an opinion as fact and implying that it is SOP.  Personally, when working on projects with other people I _always_ add  "/.gitignore" to .gitignore as there is no reason it should change regularly and I like people to be able to add their own entries to it without them getting pushed back to the base repo. There are dozens of scenarios I could list in which sharing changes to .gitignore would be problematic, most of which should be self apparent.

Comment: @JustinBuser Thats not an opinion, but it's the reason why `.gitignore` exists. That it doesn't change frequently doesn't care, you can add files, that will _never_ change to git.  The use case for `.gitignore` is, that it is part of the repository and that it _should_ get shared with every clone. That is nothing i've invented ;) To add own entries there are even _two_ additional locations, means: No reason to misuse `.gitignore` for that. Maybe you want to describe the other 11 of the dozens scenarios?

Comment: Sorry for changing the correct answer to @Justin's. But he has a way to do it.

Comment: @ArunMozhi But you read (and understand) my comments? Using `.gitignore` this way makes it _completely identical_ to the one defined in `core.excludesfile`, or `$GIT_DIR/info/exclude` respectively _and_ you take yourself the possibility to introduce a versioned ignore file. It's like taking taking of the motor from a motorcycle, because you want a bike, even if you aleady ave one ^^

Comment: I understand it, and my repositories **always** have the `.gitignore` files in them. From a QA point, there is a question and there is a answer. Thats it.